# Devise keeps going into an infinite loop on the sign_in path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I generated a user devise model and styled the sign_up form.All was working well however whenever I signed up I would get an infinite loop error.So I redirected the page to go to users#show after the signup was successful.I specified as users#show as my root and now even though I don't have any users in the database it goes to the users#show so I added a before_action :authenticate_user! to the top of my users controller.the problem now is that it keeps going to the sign_in page and then into an infinite loop and I can't seem to fix it.

Here are my routes

```
resources :users
root : 'users#show'

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :regsitrations => "registrations" }
```

Here is the RegistrationController for redirecting after signup

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    return users_path(resource)
  end
end
```

Here is my UsersController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

What could be the problem? why is it going into an infinite loop and how might i get it to show the users#show if the user is signed in and redirect to the sign_in page if they are not without going into an infinite loop?

Comment: You really shouldn't use root to: 'users#show', otherwise it always redirect there. If you want to redirect the user after it registers then you should use redirect_to user_show_path (change this to your route, if you don't know what is it, use rake routes in your console). Plus it's :registrations => not :regsitrations =>

Comment: And you really should use before_filter :authenticate_user! in your ApplicationsController and not in your users controller (just my opinion)